# jQuery ajax is not working when send post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i try to use ajxt to send post request to my restful service 
here is my ajax code

```
var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();   
var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();   
//xmlhttp.open("GET","http://192.168.1.100:8080/MapDemo/service/add?name=hieugie333&longitude=123&latitude=321",true);
//xmlhttp.send();
//document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
var JSONObject= {"name":name, "longitude":lng,"latitude":lat };
var jsonData = JSON.parse( JSONObject );    

var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://192.168.1.100:8080/MapDemo/service/add",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: jsonData,
  dataType: "json"
});
```

can anyone help me in this case ?

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful error message. Please try to provide more detail.

Comment: server is still running but it can't send post request to server. Nothing happen when i run code above

Comment: open the developer console (F12 in Google Chrome) and open the network tab. Look if a request is sent and check this request

Answer (score 1):

```
var JSONObject= {"name":name, "longitude":lng,"latitude":lat };
```

That is a JavaScript object, not a JSON text.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse( JSONObject );
```

That will error (or return `null`) because you aren't passing it a string containing a JSON text.

Your later code is expecting a string containing a JSON text though.

You want `JSON.stringify` not `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your "JSON.parse" to "JSON.stringify". You called the opposite function that you should have.